# How to grab a complete table hidden beyond 'Show all' by web scraping in Python

Tags: python, pandas

According to the reply I found in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67144542/while-web-scraping-for-a-table-in-python-an-empty-table-is-returned/67144576#67144576), I am able to grab the table by web **scraping** in Python from the URL: `https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2021/world/covid-vaccinations-tracker.html` But it only grabs partially until the row "Show all" is appeared.

How can I grab the complete table in Python which is hidden beyond "Show all" ?

Here is the code I am using:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#
vaccineDF = pd.read_html('https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2021/world/covid-vaccinations-tracker.html')[0]
vaccineDF = vaccineDF.reset_index(drop=True)
print(vaccineDF.head(100))
```

The output only grabs 15 rows (until Show All):

```
   Unnamed: 0_level_0 Doses administered  ... Unnamed: 8_level_0 Unnamed: 9_level_0
   Unnamed: 0_level_1     Per 100 people  ... Unnamed: 8_level_1 Unnamed: 9_level_1
0               World                 11  ...                NaN                NaN
1              Israel                116  ...                NaN                NaN
2          Seychelles                116  ...                NaN                NaN
3              U.A.E.                 99  ...                NaN                NaN
4               Chile                 69  ...                NaN                NaN
5             Bahrain                 66  ...                NaN                NaN
6              Bhutan                 63  ...                NaN                NaN
7                U.K.                 62  ...                NaN                NaN
8       United States                 61  ...                NaN                NaN
9          San Marino                 60  ...                NaN                NaN
10           Maldives                 59  ...                NaN                NaN
11              Malta                 55  ...                NaN                NaN
12             Monaco                 53  ...                NaN                NaN
13            Hungary                 45  ...                NaN                NaN
14             Serbia                 44  ...                NaN                NaN
15           Show all           Show all  ...           Show all           Show all
```

Below is the screen shot of the partial table until "Show all" in the web (left part) and corresponding inspect elements (right part):
[image]

Comment: Why not just grab the `json` files and get your data directly from them; one, or all of them, should give you all that you want: [link1](https://static01.nyt.com/newsgraphics/2021/01/19/world-vaccinations-tracker/782a2aed752bf692bfc37493af3d32c3b738bb3f/all_with_rate.json), [link2](https://static01.nyt.com/newsgraphics/2021/01/19/world-vaccinations-tracker/782a2aed752bf692bfc37493af3d32c3b738bb3f/continent_vaccinations.json), [link3](https://static01.nyt.com/newsgraphics/2021/01/19/world-vaccinations-tracker/782a2aed752bf692bfc37493af3d32c3b738bb3f/vaccinations_country.json)

Comment: I think the link to the json is [this](https://static01.nyt.com/newsgraphics/2021/01/19/world-vaccinations-tracker/782a2aed752bf692bfc37493af3d32c3b738bb3f/latest.json)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48160554/using-python-requests-to-simulate-clicking-a-show-more-button Content of the complete table (after 'show more' button) is created/added dynamically, but, as explained from others, there are better ways to get the data.

Comment: It’s __scraping__ (and __scrape__, __scraped__) not scrapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't print whole data directly because you can see your full data after clicking the `Show all` Button. So, from this scenario, we can understand that first of all we have to first create an `on click()` event for clicking the `Show all` Button then we can fetch the whole table.

I have used `Selenium` Library for the `on click` event for pressing the `Show all` Button. For this particular scenario, I have used `Firefox() Webdriver` of `Selenium` for fetching all `data` from `url`. Kindly refer to the code given below for fetching the whole table of the given `COVID Dataset URL`:-

```
# Import all the Important Libraries
from selenium import webdriver # This module help to fetch data and on-click event purpose
from pandas.io.html import read_html # This module will help to read 'html' source. So, we can __scrape__ data from it
import pandas as pd # This Module will help to Convert Our Data into 'DataFrame'
  
# Create 'FireFox' Webdriver Object
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# Get Website
driver.get("https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2021/world/covid-vaccinations-tracker.html")

# Find 'Show all' Button Using 'XPath'
show_all_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/main/article/section/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[16]")

# Click 'Show all' Button
show_all_button.click()

# Get 'HTML' Content of Page
html_data = driver.page_source
```

After fetching the whole data, let's see how many tables are there in our `COVID Dataset URL`

```
covid_data_tables = read_html(html_data,  attrs = {"class":"g-summary-table  svelte-2wimac"}, header = None)

# Print Number of Tables Extracted
print ("\nExtracted {num} COVID Data Table".format(num = len(covid_data_tables)), "\n")
```

```
# Output of Above Cell:-

Extracted 1 COVID Data Table
```

Now, let's fetch the Data Table:-

```
# Print Table Data

covid_data_tables[0].head(20)
```

```
# Output of above cell:-
Unnamed: 0_level_0      Doses administered         Pct. of population
Unnamed: 0_level_1      Per 100 people  Total      Vaccinated   Fully vaccinated
0   World               11              877933955  –            –
1   Israel              116             10307583   60%          56%
2   Seychelles          116             112194     68%          47%
3   U.A.E.              99              9489684    –            –
4   Chile               69              12934282   41%          28%
5   Bahrain             66              1042463    37%          29%
6   Bhutan              63              478219     63%          –
7   U.K.                62              41505768   49%          13%
8   United States       61              202282923  38%          24%
9   San Marino          60              20424      35%          25%
10  Maldives            59              303752     53%          5.6%
11  Malta               55              264658     38%          17%
12  Monaco              53              20510      30%          23%
13  Hungary             45              4416581    32%          14%
14  Serbia              44              3041740    26%          17%
15  Qatar               43              1209648    –            –
16  Uruguay             38              1310591    30%          8.3%
17  Singapore           30              1667522    20%          9.5%
18  Antigua and Barbuda 28              27032      28%          –
19  Iceland             28              98672      20%          8.1%
```

As you can see it was not showing `show all` in our dataset. So, Now we can Convert this `Data Table` to `DataFrame`. For doing this task we have to store this `Data` into `CSV` Format and we can reupload it and store it in `DataFrame`. The code for the Same was stated below:-

```
# HTML Table to CSV Format Conversion For COVID Dataset
covid_data_file = 'covid_data.csv'
covid_data_tables[0].to_csv(covid_data_file, sep = ',')

# Read CSV Data From Data Table for Further Analysis
covid_data = pd.read_csv("covid_data.csv")
```

So, after Storing all the `Data` into `csv` Format let's convert data into `DataFrame` Format and Print Whole data:-

```
# Store 'CSV' Data into 'DataFrame' Format
vaccineDF = pd.DataFrame(covid_data)
vaccineDF = vaccineDF.drop(columns=["Unnamed: 0"], axis = 1) # 'drop' Unneccesary Columns from the Dataset

# Print Whole Dataset
vaccineDF
```

```
# Output of above cell:-
    Unnamed: 0_level_0  Doses administered  Doses administered.1    Pct. of population  Pct. of population.1
0   Unnamed: 0_level_1  Per 100 people      Total                   Vaccinated          Fully vaccinated
1   World               11                  877933955               –                   – 
2   Israel              116                 10307583                60%                 56%
3   Seychelles          116                 112194                  68%                 47%
4   U.A.E.              99                  9489684                 –                   –
... ...                 ...                 ...                     ...                 ...
154 Syria               <0.1                2500                    <0.1%               –
155 Papua New Guinea    <0.1                1081                    <0.1%               –
156 South Sudan         <0.1                947                     <0.1%               –
157 Cameroon            <0.1                400                     <0.1%               –
158 Zambia              <0.1                106                     <0.1%               –

159 rows × 5 columns
```

From above Output we can see that we have successfully fetched whole `data table`. Hope this Solution will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Yes, using the Selenium webdriver, I could grab the full table. However, I had to: 1) install the geckodriver in the path of Python, 2) introduce time.sleep(2) before and after the "show_all" press, 3) (I also introduced) driver.quit() to close the opened browser after I read all data and before writing to .csv. Anyway everything working as I expect.

Answer (score 0):

- [OWID](https://ourworldindata.org) provides this data, which effectively comes from JHU
- if you want latest vaccination data by country,  it's simple to use CSV interface

```
import requests, io
dfraw = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/vaccinations/vaccinations.csv").text))
dfraw["date"] = pd.to_datetime(dfraw["date"])

dfraw.sort_values(["iso_code","date"]).groupby("iso_code", as_index=False).last()
```